# Как узнать какой тип ключа в цикле?

Tags: javascript

При использовании разных циклов все ключи по разному но сводятся к одному типу.

Нужно в цикле определять какой тип ключа у конкретной итерации, как такое сделать?

```js
let arr = [];

arr[0] = 0;
arr[1] = 1;
arr["2"] = 2;

for (let i of arr) {
  console.log(typeof(i));
}
for (let i in arr) {
  console.log(typeof(i));
}
arr.forEach(i => console.log(typeof(i)));
```

Comment: уверен, что в js arr["2"] = 2; отличается чем-то от arr[2] = 2;?

Comment: @xmikex, вот блин) я и забыл что в js в массивах нет такого понятия как ключи, перепутал с  языком php)) а в объект не переведешь там ключи всегда с типом строки будут. Какой то парадок не понятный, и не понятно что делать

Comment: В for in `i`-это индексы в forEach и for of `i`-это значения